# Find last cell value in array

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, lookup

I'm looking for a vba code to find the last value in an array in a column. It's also possible with the function LOOKUP(C1; A:B) but I would like to do it with VBA. I've already tried to use the function:
x = Application.Worksheetfunction.Lookup(Range("C1"), Range("A:B"))
But it didn't work. The data looks something like this:

- **A  :  B**
- 1  :  10
- 1  :  12
- 2  :  20
- 2  :  25
- 2  :  30
- 3  :  35
- 3  :  40
- 4   : 45
- 4  :  50
- 4  :    55

So for 1 it has to return 12, for 2 -> 30, for 3 -> 40 and for 4 -> 55.

Comment: Why do you want to do it in vba if you're using the identical function as the worksheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**edited** after OP's further request

I guess you may be after this:

```
With Range("C1")
    If IsError(Application.Match(.Value, Range("A:A"), 0)) Then
        MsgBox "Sorry, no match for " & .Value & " in column A"
    Else
        Range("H7").Value = Application.VLookup(.Value, Range("A:B"), 2)
    End If
End With
```

Comment: I think it's working! What can I add to drop the value of x in cell H7?

Comment: start with accepting the answer! And I'll follow up in a moment

Answer (score 0):

Using your example, I think you want:

```
Application.Worksheetfunction.VLookup(Range("C1"), Range("A:B"),2)
```